# jooq issue with limit and offset

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate, jooq, bind-variables

I have integrated jooq with spring and for all types of querying to the database (MySQL), I am using JDBC Template of spring. jooq library is used here to generate the sql query to pass to jdbc template.

Though my rest of the query works fine until I add limit and/or offset to the query.

I am generating query as follows:

```
create.select(Factory.field("table_name"))
      .from("tables t")
      .where("t.table_schema LIKE '" + schemaName + "'")
      .limit(10)
      .offset(2)
      .getSQL();
```

I am getting error as follows:

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback;
>   bad SQL grammar [select table_name from tables t where (t.table_schema
>   LIKE 'test') limit ? offset ?]; nested exception is
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '? offset ?' at
>   line 1

Which clearly says that the values passed to limit and offset method are not appended to the query.

I searched on the documentation but not found any other way to achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jOOQ generates SQL with bind values. As you're using jOOQ to render SQL only, executing it with Spring, you essentially have any of these options:

#### Use inlined bind values, explicitly:

Like this, you can explicitly tell jOOQ not to render any bind variables for your `LIMIT .. OFFSET` clause

```
create.select(DSL.field("table_name"))
      .from("tables t")
      .where("t.table_schema LIKE '" + schemaName + "'")
      .limit(DSL.inline(10))
      .offset(DSL.inline(2))
      .getSQL();
```

#### Let jOOQ inline all bind values:

Like this, you can tell jOOQ not to render any bind variables at all:

```
Settings settings = new Settings();
settings.setStatementType(StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT);
DSLContext create = DSL.using(connection, dialect, settings);
// [...]
```

#### Extract bind values from jOOQ's query:

Like this, you can let jOOQ render bind variables where appropriate, and extract them in the right order:

```
Query query =
create.select(DSL.field("table_name"))
      .from("tables t")
      .where("t.table_schema LIKE '" + schemaName + "'")
      .limit(DSL.inline(10))
      .offset(DSL.inline(2));

String sql = query.getSQL();
List<Object> bindValues = query.getBindValues();
```

#### More information on jOOQ's understanding about bind values:

http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/bind-values/

#### Note about syntax integrity and SQL injection

Beware that your query is somewhat error-prone, in that `schemaName` should be checked and escaped in case it originates from user input. You can create a bind value for it as such:

```
create.select(DSL.field("table_name"))
      .from("tables t")
      .where("t.table_schema LIKE ?", schemaName)
```

Comment: Thanks Lukas...That solved my problem....And you are right about the bind value...I will keep this in mind always...although currently in this scenario it does not affect since 'schemaName' is coming from a single select list.